# Values being wrapped in optionals twice

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm encountering an incredibly frustrating situation when consuming data from my company's API. Namely, when I consume a value that I expect to be an Int (and is an Int being sent down from the backend), let's use "userID" as an example, it becomes double wrapped in an optional. I am trying to turn it into an explicitly unwrapped Int value (`var userID : Int!`), so when I take it from the API I'm doing this `self.userID = responseObject["id"] as! Int` but once I print it out I get this in lldb

```
Optional<Int>
- some : 7575235
```

so if I try to turn this into a string it becomes this

```
Optional<String>
- some : "Optional(7575235)"
```

...this has been incredibly frustrating when I do `po responseObject["id"] as! Int` in the console, it returns what I would expect it to be, which is 7575235, completely unwrapped. I don't know why once I put it in the instance variable it wraps it back up again, especially since it's explicitly unwrapped. This has been incredibly frustrating, so any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: what is the type of responseObject? [String: AnyObject]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know why once I put it in the instance variable it wraps it back up again, especially since it's explicitly unwrapped

*You* are the one who wrapped it back up again by typing `self.userID` as an `Int!`. An implicitly unwrapped Optional *is an Optional*. Assigning an Int to an Optional Int wraps it up in the Optional — and that is exactly what you did when you said

```
self.userID = responseObject["id"] as! Int
```

Do you see? `responseObject["id"] as! Int` is an Int, yes; but `self.userID` itself is an Optional wrapping an Int, so that assignment wraps the Int into an Optional.

All that it means for an Optional to be implicitly unwrapped is that if you *use* it where its wrapped type is expected, it *will* be unwrapped. For example, you could pass `self.userID` where an Int is expected and it will be unwrapped for you to retrieve the wrapped Int. But if you ask what it actually *is*, as you are doing in `lldb`, why then, it's an Optional — because *you* turned it into an Optional.

Comment: I do see that, I think my fundamental misunderstanding comes from the idea of explicitly unwrapped optionals....I thought that whenever you use them they are already unwrapped, so if I declare `userID` as an Int!, whenever I use it I don't have to explicitly unwrap it, hence the explicitly unwrapped optional designation

Comment: Right. I guessed that this was your misconception, which is why I tried to spell it out so fully in my answer. Sometimes our minds are like a malfunctioning piece of equipment and you just have to whack it on the side to get it working properly! — To be honest, Apple is trying to phase out implicitly unwrapped Optionals entirely. Their purpose was really as a stopgap in the early days, before the Cocoa APIs were adjusted. You should stop using them. They are just making you lazy. :) — See also my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_implicitly_unwrapped_optional

Comment: "implicit unwrapping does not propagate by assignment."....that's exactly what I was misunderstanding. that chapter in your book is ungodly helpful, thank you so much. everyone should read that for Swift 3 because that change in usage was a significant source of frustration for me

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:-

```
var userID = 0

self.userID = responseObject["id"] as! Int
let stringValue = String(self.userID)
```

The issue here is that `Int` is not an object type, so you need to initialise it with a value.